# Markdown in other statistics packages than R

Tags: sas, stata, knitr, spss, r-markdown

I'm a great fan of `R markdown`, finding it even easier than weaving LaTeX for quick project documentation (less than 15 pages). However, I also have to support sometimes other Statistics packages (`SPSS`, `Stata` + `SAS`) and was wondering for equivalent solutions for these.

To some extend this might go back to using some kind of original `Noweb` code + markdown file to be compiled over the command line. I guess calling the other packages from R is another option.

I have had a look at this example by John Muschelli: http://rpubs.com/muschellij2/3888 and it looks as though he knitted Stata code into an R markdown file.

Can someone provide specific examples of how this can be done in Stata, SAS or SPSS?

*I do know of `SASweave` and `StatWeave` (the latter is apparently broken???), but think that a markdown solution would be far more advantageous in our case.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Muschelli pointed me to this Stata program:

https://github.com/amarder/stata-tutorial/blob/master/knitr.do

It parses a `.domd` file which contains markdown and Stata code and produces a `.md` file with executed Stata code. The name of the file to be parsed is at the end of the `knitr.do` file.

More specifcally:

1. Download the `knitr.do` file from https://github.com/amarder/stata-tutorial/blob/master/knitr.do
2. Download the `clustered-standard-errors.domd` file from https://github.com/amarder/stata-tutorial/blob/master/clustered-standard-errors.domd
3. Save them both in some directory.
4. Modify the last line of `knitr.do` to reflect the complete path of its directory (e.g. 
   **D:\Desktop\knit_example\clustered-standard-errors.domd**
5. Run `knitr.do` to get your markdown (`.md`) file (and an intermediate `.md1` file).

Note that `knitr.do` contains the programs that do the work and a line (the last one):

```
knit "whatever-file.domd"
```

that calls the program.

So you basically write a `.domd` file [that of step (2) is only an example] containing Markdown syntax and Stata commands, run `knitr.do` adjusting the file name, and get a Markdown file with executed Stata commands.

There are several caveats:

- Only one-liner Stata commands are allowed. A loop, for example, won't work.
- ".domd" can't be part of the file name.
- If there is an error with a Stata command, the user gets no return code.
- File handles need to be manually closed if user hits the *Break* button when the program is running or if there is a Stata command error.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand in which order I need to run the scripts and how to modify it, but it looks like the correct thing! Thanks

Comment: I've added some details to my answer.  I hope they help.

Answer (score 6):

Stata has its own SMCL for annotation of logs, the M standing for mark-up. The main reason for a different language is that SMCL has to be created and interpreted line by line in situations where no end of document is in sight, namely within interactive sessions. This is created by Stata automatically as annotation when you ask for it and can be stipulated by users or programmers as a way of tuning Stata's display choices.

The possible connection to your question is that SMCL can be translated to HTML, which opens various doors. So, something that is easy in Stata is to do some work, keep a `log` file in SMCL and then translate the log file to HTML. You would not get anything really nice without further work, but the further work is easy and amounts to doing what you would done any way, but in your favourite text editor or text processor, rather than within Stata.

This is made easier by `log2html` which Stata users can install using `ssc inst log2html`. It exploits a feature undocumented in Stata.

Stata's help files can also be translated to HTML in the same way (but consider copyright issues if doing this with official help files; it's fair play with your own help files).

Comment: That's an interesting approach thanks. Another solution for a reproducible document would be to use Stata inside Word with the SAR macro http://www.stata.com/meeting/italy11/abstracts/italy11_lo_magno.pdf

Comment: I guess so. There's no accounting for taste....

Comment: @JoanneDemmler Joanne, please post your comment as an answer. Almost missed it. And it seems that Haghish's solutions (under active development) will be the closest thing to `knitr' Stat could ever get.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you're looking to create .html files in SAS that contain statistical reports within them, then you can use the Output Delivery System (ODS).

Example syntax is:

```
ods html file='pathofdirectory\filename.html' <additional options>;
    proc print...  (SAS code that generates output)
    proc means...
    proc freq...
    proc gchart...
    proc gplot...
    ...        
ods html close;
```

Comment: I actually want to go a bit further than the ods setup and include a large number of other input into the report, i.e. a lot of text, images, citations (pandoc + latex) and single numbers grabbed from the  statistics table. The result should be something like this http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/324-2012.pdf - that is a fully reproducible and self contained analysis document. Preferably the methods for all the different stats packages should be as similar as possible.

Answer (score 1):

SPSS (and SAS I presume) have some overhead by the need to write everything to disk that makes the compilation in one fell swoop less appealing. Similar as to what Yick mentioned, SPSS has an output system that one can write automated reports to begin with and export to HTML or PDF or Word. It isn't the easiest thing to make look nice, but it is possible and additions to ease automated editing (mainly via Python scripts) are being rolled out on a regular basis.

Basically the automated reports I write now using SPSS and R have html shells. The code then just updates or inserts the needed tables and graphs. They are entirely self-contained, reproducible, and run on weekly or monthly timers without human intervention. They just don't have inline code blocks exactly defining how the tables are produced (you would have to trace the code slightly further back to figure it out - but that isn't too onerous IMO).

Because SPSS allows you to run SPSS code from the Python command prompt you could theoretically knit a document with Python code calling SPSS. I'm not quite sure I see the advantage of this over having more segmented code in seperate places though. Do you really want to read 100 lines of SPSS code that begins with an SQL query, does some transformations and produces a table and a graph? Wouldn't you rather see the table and graph, and then if interested in the nitty gritty go back to see `DataPrep.sps` that prepares all of the data, then see `Table1.sps` and `Figure1.sps` etc. to see how they each were exactly produced?

Comment: I think the answer is that for a fully reproducible example you would want to include the code into the document or at least produce the output in the exact same instance. But I do like the idea of a Python-SPSS interface!

Comment: The default behavior of SPSS is to include the syntax automatically in Notes objects in the Viewer.  SPSS also supports a journal file that captures almost everything done in a session.

(SPSS also includes Java, R, and .NET interfaces)